# Reactjs/Redux create a notification when redux action is done

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a custom notification component. The idea is that when an redux action is done like login_fail, notification will pop up and hide it after few seconds, showing the message. But I am unable to make it working well. The message in the notification pop up 0.1s and then render nothing. The whole notification keep staying there and does not disappear. I guess there is something wrong in my Notification.js.

[image]

after 0.1s,
[image]

In my App.js,

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

import Notification from './utilities/Notification/NotificationTest';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/NavBar';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import Error from './pages/Error/Error';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Notification />
      <NavBar />
        <Route render={({ location }) => (
          <TransitionGroup>
            <CSSTransition key={location.key} timeout={450} classNames="fade">
              <Switch location={location}>
                <Route exact path="/" render={props => <Home {...props} />} />
                <Route component={Error} />
              </Switch>
            </CSSTransition>
          </TransitionGroup>
        )} />
      </NextPageToTop>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In my UserReducer.jsx,

```
import UserActionTypes from './User.types';

const INITITAL_STATE = {
    userState: [],
    isLogin: false,
    hasError: false,
    message: '',
}

const userReducer = (state = INITITAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UserActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
             return {
                isLogin: true,
                userState: action.payload, //userData
                hasError: false,
                message: action.payload.status, // message from api (e.g. 'Login 
                Successfully')
            };

        case UserActionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL:
            return {
                isLogin: false,
                userState: [],
                hasError: true,
                message: action.payload.status, (e.g. 'Login Fail')
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default userReducer;
```

In my User.actions.jsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import UserActionTypes from './User.types';

export const LoginAction = (loginState, history) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post("api/login", loginState);
            const { data } = res;
            dispatch({ type: UserActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data });
            history.push("/");
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                dispatch({
                    type: UserActionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL,
                    payload: error.response.data.message,
                });
            }
        }
    };
};
```

In my Notification.js,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Notification.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Notification = (props, duration = 5000) => {
    const { message, error } = props;
    const [showNotification, setShowNotification] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setShowNotification(true);

        setTimeout(() => setShowNotification(false), duration)
    }, [duration])

    return (
        <div className="notification-container">
            {showNotification ? `${message}` : null}
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    error: state.user.hasError,
    message: state.user.message,
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(Notification)
```

Any Solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your notification component try this :

```
return showNotification ?
    <div className="notification-container">
        {message}
    </div>
    :null
);
```

Also your duration should be inside props , like this:

```js
const Notification = ({message, duration}) => {
    const [showNotification, setShowNotification] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setShowNotification(true);
        setTimeout(() => setShowNotification(false), duration)
    }, [duration])

    return showNotification ?(
        <div className="notification-container">
            {message}
        </div>
    ):null;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Notification message={"notification"} duration={5000} />
  ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.notification-container {
  background-color: red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it pop up at a 0.1s and turn off immediately. How do I deal with it?

Comment: @sam1024 ill make u an example .